# Deploying app in aws throws error java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

Good day developers , im working in this Angular+MySQL+Spring-Boot app, and i'm in that phase of exporting my database to AWS, but for any reason after having tested the database connection to my  mySQL Workbench , when i set the parameters in the application.properties the error  `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected` appears.

The endpoint AWS throws as well as the port are :

```
endpoint: bookingrestaurantok.clnhc7kmwszz.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

port: 3306
```

thus using this elements on my app.properties i just initialize

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://bookingrestaurantok.clnhc7kmwszz.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
:3306/restaurant_booking_ok?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

spring.datasource.username=ssssssssssss
spring.datasource.password=sssssssssssssss

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

I'm exposing here the workbench database and its endpoint

[image]

[image]

But any time i try to reach whichever the endpoints in my app the error 500 of no database selected shows up. Could you help me to see what step im  ommiting

I know is a lot of code but also i attach my pom in case you detect something is wrong there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>cubancoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>restaurant-booking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restaurant-booking</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot made on maven  front end angular</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail 
            dependencia para el envio de emails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stripe/stripe-java dependencia para el wireling de pagos
        y demas-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
            <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
            <version>19.45.0</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you share the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected` seems to refer to the database name.

The database name is set correctly in the property `spring.datasource.url`, however for Amazon RDS it's enough to point that property to the endpoint (without the database name). Try the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://bookingrestaurantok.clnhc7kmwszz.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
:3306
```

### Edit:

I was able to reproduce the error. The issue is that Amazon RDS by default creates a new database instance but not a database. To create a database there is this option to set:

[image]

Also, the error does not appear after connecting to the database, but only after the first query (for example creating a new table).

Setting "Initial database name" to `mydb` and having a database instance id `database-instance-1`, then the URL would be:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database-instance-1.blablabla.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb
```

I know that your `spring.datasource.url` looks correct and you can see your database in Workbench but I suggest you create a new database instance using the Amazon RDS dashboard and setting the database name as explained above.

It's not a definitive answer but I hope this tentative will let you figure out the cause of the issue.

Comment: Keeps the same problem, and yes the database schema name matches with the name:restaurant_booking_ok set in the path "...3306/restaurant_booking_ok....."

Comment: @EnriqueGF Got it, I updated my answer with an additional suggestion. It's not a definite answer but I hope it helps.

Comment: i have done that since the beginning but neither works

Answer (score -1):

1. Please check the connectivity between the node in which application is deployed and the instance in which DB is there.
2. Have you provided enough permissions for both nodes for communications ?.
3. Do ping from application machine to db machine.
4. Install mysql client in application machine and try to connect to the db.
5. Is the database available in that database server ?

Comment: could you be more specific Hakuna

Comment: Check the accessibility of the two nodes (app & db), use ping / telnet the 3306 among both nodes.

Comment: did you mean a test connection to that endpoint from my MySql...if is that i already did it and connection works perfect to that endpoint and the port

Comment: Then try other options